# correctly redirect user if refresh token has expired using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using Axios in the frontend of my project and needed a way to redirect the user to the login page in case he wanted to used expired tokens (the refresh token is invalid for the backend), I found a [boilerplate code](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/690#issuecomment-278372400) on the web that looked easy enough to adapt for my tech stack (ReactJS with no Redux):

```
import axios from 'axios';

// additional code that lives in its own module
const getToken = () => {
  return isAuth() ? window.localStorage.getItem("token") : "";
};

const getRefreshToken = () => {
  return isAuth() ? window.localStorage.getItem("refresh_token") : "";
};

const setTokens = (token, refresh) => {
  window.localStorage.setItem("token", token);
  window.localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", refresh);
};
// this is on my app.js file
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  const originalRequest = error.config;
  if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
    originalRequest._retry = true;
    // Hace la solicitud de refresco de tokens
    return axios.get('/api/v1/auth', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getRefreshToken()}})
      .then((responseData) => {
        // actualiza la información de OAuth
        setTokens(responseData.data.access_token, responseData.data.refresh_token);
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        // re-intenta la solicitud original
        return axios(originalRequest);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setTokens(undefined, undefined);
        window.location.pathname = "/login";
      });
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

The problem is that the code enters in a infinite recursion leaving the frontend unusable. if I navigate manually to `/login` the recursion stops entirely.

### EDIT

Here is the entire source code of the file where I just had to do the changes according to the solution accepted for my questio:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import {Router} from 'react-router';

import Fero from './containers/Fero/Fero';
import {setTokens, getRefreshToken, getToken} from './utils/auth';

import axios from 'axios';

const myhistory = createHistory();


axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  const originalRequest = error.config;
  if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
    originalRequest._retry = true;
    // Hace la solicitud de refresco de tokens
    return axios.get('/api/v1/auth', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getRefreshToken()}})
      .then((responseData) => {
        // actualiza la información de OAuth
        setTokens(responseData.data.access_token, responseData.data.refresh_token);
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        // re-intenta la solicitud original
        return axios(originalRequest);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setTokens(undefined, undefined);
        myhistory.replace("/login");
      });
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={myhistory}>
          <Fero/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should consider using react-router for handling URL changes.

Comment: @Peter I'm actually using React Router components, but, how do I use it inside the interceptor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it turns out the solution to the recursion was using a different instance of axios for the token refreshment so the interceptor did not intercept the HTTP 401 response for a expired refresh token, here is the full solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import {Router} from 'react-router';

import Fero from './containers/Fero/Fero';
import {setTokens, getRefreshToken, getToken} from './utils/auth';

import axios from 'axios';

const myhistory = createHistory();
const refresh = axios.create();


axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  const originalRequest = error.config;
  if (error.response.status === 401 && Boolean(getRefreshToken())) {
    // Hace la solicitud de refresco de tokens
    return refresh.get('/api/v1/auth', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getRefreshToken()}})
      .then((responseData) => {
        // actualiza la información de OAuth
        setTokens(responseData.data.access_token, responseData.data.refresh_token);
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
        // re-intenta la solicitud original
        return axios(originalRequest);
      }).catch((error) => {
        setTokens("", "");
        myhistory.replace("/login");
      });
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={myhistory}>
        <Fero/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

the content of `src/utils/auth.js`:

```
export const isAuth = () => {
  return window.localStorage.getItem("token") && window.localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
};

export const getToken = () => {
  return isAuth() ? window.localStorage.getItem("token") : "";
};

export const getRefreshToken = () => {
  return isAuth() ? window.localStorage.getItem("refresh_token") : "";
};

export const setTokens = (token, refresh) => {
  window.localStorage.setItem("token", token);
  window.localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", refresh);
};
```

Comment: import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'; i dont know this get from your code or dependency. can you tell me what it?

Answer (score 2):

It is a good problem, and I did not know about axios interceptors. Anyway, I found a solution for this problem. The main thing is that you have to wrap your interceptor setup in a function, so you can pass the history object as a parameter.
And you need the history object. One possible solution is to create one and provide the same history object to the Router as well the wrapped interceptor setup.

```js
// in app.js create a history
const history = createHistory();

// with the history object, setup your interceptor
setupInterceptor(history)

// you have to use the same history object in your 
// Router component, if it is in a different component 
// you could pass it in a prop

     <Router history={history}>
        ...
     </Router>


const setupInterceptor = (history) => {
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  const originalRequest = error.config;

  // ...

      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setTokens(undefined, undefined);
        history.push("/login");
      });
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
})};
```

Comment: I tested now with a production build and the recursion is still happening for some estrange reason, testing in the development build of the frontend (`yarn start`) it works as intended

Comment: I figured out what was the issue in reality, so I need to choose the correct answer. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: Don't worry, I'm glad you found the problem